# Syntax for Excel Object. Change Number Formatting

Tags: sql, excel, extract, powerbuilder, vba

I made an application that extracts records from an SQL Select to Excel.
I would like to change the number formatting of the excel columns before saving. I made the EXCEL OLE Object then writes data on to it

```
Excel_Sheet.Cells[i + j,k] =  s_col
```

I would like to change the number format depending on the column type. I already know how to get the column type but have no luck in changing the number format.

I used these: to make the headers Bold and change the width depending on the data using AutoFit.. All I've found in the internet:

```
Excel_Sheet.Range(s_into_row + String(j) + ":" +s_into_col + String(j)).Select
Excel_Obj.Selection.Font.Bold = True

Excel_Sheet.Range("A"+String(j)+":A"+String(j)).Select
Excel_Sheet.Columns(s_into_row + ":" + s_into_col ).EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

I am using powerbuilder

Comment: I haven't worked with Powerbuilder but have you tried something like `Excel_Sheet.Columns(s_into_row).NumberFormat = "0.00"`

Comment: hey it worked, never thought it was that simple. thanks for the answer, i know pb is irrelevant but i just tried mentioning it. Thanks a lot sir. how do i mark your answer as correct :D thanks again

Comment: @SiddharthRout: *you* could post the answer so that Sid would accept it. Credits to the solution belong to you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't worked with Powerbuilder but have you tried something like

```
Excel_Sheet.Columns(s_into_row).NumberFormat = "0.00"
```

Answer (score 2):

I've got some code in a project that looks similar to this:

```
choose case lower(ls_coltype)
    case "char"
        lole_Excel.Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    case "date"
        lole_Excel.Selection.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    case "int", "long", "ulong"
        lole_Excel.Selection.NumberFormat = "0"
    case "time"
        lole_Excel.Selection.NumberFormat = "h:mm AM/PM"
    ...
end choose
```

where ls_coltype is the column type with the "(" and everything after removed.